# Bat Script for Checking gpg Signature

Tags: batch-file, gnupg

i know you can check the gpg signature with gpg --verify filename but i need that in an .bat script

Script should work like when you signature is correct move it to folder "sig_ok" when signature is bad move it to folder "sig_notok"

Can anyone help me i have problems with ckecking the signature in the script and save it in a variable or what ever .. i tried it with

```
for /f "delims=?" %%i in ('gpg2.exe --verify C:\temp\test.txt.gpg.asc ^| findstr "gpg: "') do (...
```

BR
Dominik

Comment: Did you try with `"delims="` ?

Comment: Two things: first, it's probably worth including sample output from `gpg2` for both cases: many people could help with a batch file who won't know what the output is.  Second, does `gpg2` set `%ERRORLEVEL%` based on the validity?  Try `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` immediately after manually running `gpg2` for both good and bad signatures.

Comment: it worked with errorlevel variable you were right thank you very much!

Comment: @Dominik, if you found a sokution yourself, consider to share it by posting it as an answer...